# Convert a SQL query to the ElasticSearch query

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

I wrote this query in SQL and now I needed it in the elastic search.
How can I do that?

```
select * from listings where condition1 = true or (condition2 = 1 and condition3 = false)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```json
POST listings/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "condition1": {
              "value": "true"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "condition2": {
                    "value": "1"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "condition3": {
                    "value": "false"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You need to use `should` clause for `or` and `must` clause for `and`.

You need to use `term` or `match` query based on your requirement.